# All the pictures which uploaded to database getting size 0kb

Tags: android

```
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,bytes);
    byte[]imageBytes = bytes.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }
```

I try to uploading the picture from Android Studio to MySQL with XAMPP, that's uploaded successfully to my database at there but when I check in my folder, the picture size is 0 kb.

Comment: Did you save the encodedImage to database then decode it to bitmap to your folder?

Comment: how can i save the encodeImage, can you tell me please? i'm a fresh meat at android

Comment: I'm still can't understand your whole question. First, how do you upload your image? is it via simple file uploading or sending encodedImage string via post?. Second, what is the relation between your code above with checking picture size in folder?

Comment: em,first i uploaded by sending encodedImage string via post, and second i want to know if there are some mistakes in my code above